# Find the maximum number of points that lie on the same straight line

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, computational-geometry

Given n points on a 2D plane, find the maximum number of points that lie on the same straight line.

This programming puzzle is taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-points-on-a-line/) on Leetcode

Below is my attempt to solve it.

```
   /**
     * Definition for a point.
     * class Point {
     *     int x;
     *     int y;
     *     Point() { x = 0; y = 0; }
     *     Point(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
     * }
     */
    public class Solution {
        public int maxPoints(Point[] points) {
            if (points.length==0) return 0;
            Map[] maps = new Map[points.length];
            for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
                Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
                maps[i] = map;
            }
            //count the points with the same coordinates
            int [] identical = new int[points.length];

            //count the points that form a vertical line against the x-axis
            int [] vertical = new int[points.length];
            for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
                for (int j=i+1; j<points.length; j++) {
                    Point A = points[i];
                    Point B = points[j];
                    if (A.x != B.x) {
                        double slope = (A.y-B.y)/(A.x-B.x);
                        if (maps[i].containsKey(slope)) {
                            maps[i].put(slope, (int)maps[i].get(slope)+1);
                        } else {
                            maps[i].put(slope, 1);
                        }
                        if (maps[j].containsKey(slope)) {
                            maps[j].put(slope, (int)maps[j].get(slope)+1);
                        } else {
                            maps[j].put(slope, 1);
                        }
                    } else if (A.y == B.y) {
                        identical[i]++;
                        identical[j]++;
                    } else {
                        vertical[i]++;
                        vertical[j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int max = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
                int maxForCurrentPoint = vertical[i];
                for (Object entry : maps[i].entrySet())
                {
                    int num = (int)((Map.Entry)entry).getValue();
                    if (num > maxForCurrentPoint) {
                        maxForCurrentPoint = num;
                    }
                }
                maxForCurrentPoint += identical[i]+1; //the extra 1 counts for the point itself
                if (maxForCurrentPoint > max)
                max = maxForCurrentPoint;
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
```

However, I was not able to pass the test cases. The testing results are as follows:

> 19 / 27 test cases passed.
>
> Input:    [[84,250],[0,0],[1,0],[0,-70],[0,-70],[1,-1],[21,10],[42,90],[-42,-230]]
>   Output:   8 Expected: 6

The logic of my code seems okay to me, but perhaps I'm missing something I'm not aware of? I also have doubt about the usage of hashtable here. Could anyone please shed some light on the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
double slope = (A.y-B.y)/(A.x-B.x);
```

is wrong. This does `int` division, and then converts the result to a `double`. You want

```
double slope = (A.y-B.y)/(double)(A.x-B.x);
```